# Swagger Editor not displaying $ref models in the Models section

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

I have the following definitions in my Swagger file (according to the Swagger Specification):

```yaml
definitions:
  ErrorItem:
    type: object
    properties:
        code:
          type: string
        message:
          type: string
        field:
          type: string
          description: field
  Error: 
    description: "List of errors"
    type: array 
    items: 
      $ref: '#/definitions/ErrorItem'
```

but in the Swagger Editor I see the following:
[image]

Is this correct? The Errors array should not visually have anything else in Models section?

Comment: Looks like a bug in Swagger UI. I suggest you report this bug at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues.

Comment: Thanks so much Helen!

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug introduced in Swagger Editor v.3.2.0 which was fixed in v.3.2.4,
 and also fixed in the online http://editor.swagger.io.